# How to use encapsulation and inheritance at the same time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

### How do I use encapsulation and inheritance at the same time?

I have this code:

```py
class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__name = "test"


class Warrior(Character):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def getName(self):
        print(self.__name)


a = Warrior()
a.getName()
```

and when I run the code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Coding Files/lear-tsc/app.py", line 15, in <module>    
    a.getName()
  File "d:/Coding Files/lear-tsc/app.py", line 11, in getName     
    print(self.__name)
AttributeError: 'Warrior' object has no attribute '_Warrior__name'
```

**How do I get rid of this error?**

Comment: if you print `vars(a)` it will show`{'_Character__name': 'test'}` so there is no attribute `__name` it is actually `_Character__name`. I think `__name` is private variable. What you are looking for is protected variable that is `_name`, like `self._name = "test"` then it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when looking at other programming languagaes (C++), private members cannot be accessed by the deriving classes. I guess you're looking for a protected member.

Either way, Python doesn't have a real private variable. You can always access it if you ask for the member explicitly. For example, on your code -

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__name = "test"


class Warrior(Character):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def getName(self):
        print(self._Character__name)


a = Warrior()
a.getName()
```

The result would be:

```
test
```

And the same action could be done outside of the subclass. Of course, this behaviour should be refrained. Since you anyway rely on the user's well behavior, I suggest that you'll rely also on Pythonic code conventions, and turn it into a "protected" member:

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = "test"


class Warrior(Character):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def getName(self):
        print(self._name)
```